# How to put an ArrayList<String> object to the props variable of jmeter and use it from Beanshell script

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to do this from a beanshell sampler.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

list = new ArrayList();
props.putObject("list", list );
```

Now from another Beahshell sampler I want to do this.

```
list = props.getObject("list");
list.add("Rajan");
```

And then from a third Bean shell sampler

```
log.info("The list is " + list );
```

The code will work if we use vars instead of props. But the scope of vars is inside a single thread only. I want an array object in the scope of the test plan.
The code throws an error. seems like props is a java.util.Properties class and cannot hold objects. Any idea how to do this.

> In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.util.List; import java.util.ArrayList;  //Prints the report list = n . . . '' Encountered "<" at line 5, column 21.

Comment: can you put the full code of exception? ty.

Answer (score 3):

`props` is, as you said, an object of type `java.util.Properties`, which is a subclass of `Hashtable`. Therefore you can use `put` and `get` methods:

```
props.put("list", list );

list = props.get("list");
```

However, The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) says this is "strongly discouraged" because it could break other operations on `Properties`. So use it at your own risk.